# Changing CSS style sheet in PHP page code

Tags: php, css

I am trying to change the CSS style sheet that is being used on a particular set of pages in php if one of the field is not filled when the page is loaded. I am very new to php, and have a slight grasp of what I'm doing. Here is the code I have right now.

```
<section class="remodel-outer" id="remodel">
    <div class="remodel.img" style="background-image">
    <?php if (empty('upload-remodel-image-here') == true) {
        $style = './httpdocs/wp-content/themes/nrd/style_img_not_fnd.css'
    } else {
        echo types_render_field("upload-remodel-image-here", array("output" => "raw"));
    } 
    echo '<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="' . $style . '">';
    ?>
    </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>

</section>
```

Comment: What is your question?  What is the desired result/output?  What is the current result/output?  What debugging have you already done?

Comment: What syntax would I use to check if the field is filled, and then change CSS style sheets if its not filled? If it's filled, I want to display a picture (which the code already does), and if not, nothing. Right now, that code has the page display nothing even if the field is filled.

Comment: "if the field is filled"  _What_ field?  There is no form shown above.  Please review the [How To Ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) section to get tips on asking a question that is more likely to get answers.

Answer (score 0):

Your mistake is probaly located right here

```
if (empty('upload-remodel-image-here') == true){...}
```

Variables in php are prefixed with a $ ([See documentation right here)](http://php.net/manual/en/language.variables.basics.php)
Right now you're checking if the string 'upload-remodel-image-here' is empty. Which will always be true. 
Try to fill a variable with the field data you want to check.

Also, if you're checking something if it's true, you can just write:

```
if (empty($variable)){...}
```